# Dropdown Box is not populating from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem in populating dropdown from mysql in php form. Database Connection is just fine. But dropdown returns empty. I have two tables. (id, name, age, etc) and admissions (admissionid, year) Each admission can have no of students. but each student can have only one admission year. I am trying this code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include ('database_connection.php');
$Studentid = $_SESSION['Studentid'];

$sql = "SELECT Admissionid FROM admissions";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
echo $result;
$dropdown = "<select name='admission_year'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['Admissionid']}'>{$row['Admissionid']}     </option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $dropdown;
?>
```

Comment: what is the output of `echo $result;`?

Comment: But when i run this query against database, it work fine

Comment: Then `SELECT Admissionid FROM admissions` query is not working or you have no data in `admissions` table. btw, is your table name `admissions`? or should it be `admission`??

Comment: i have data in admissions table. and this query works fine when i run it through phpmyadmin

Comment: echo out $row['Admissionid'] away from all that HTML. Do it in a separate echo statement and see what happens.

Comment: check the contents of database_connection.php, you might be connecting to a different database.

Comment: database connection is just fine.

Comment: @KriiV I changed it to: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['Admissionid']}'>{$row['Admissionid']}</option>";
echo $row['Admissionid'];
}
but still no successs!!!

Comment: resolved, I forgot to include $dbc in mysqli_query($sql).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looking fine, Can u pls print query result using `var_dump()`, its may be no records

Comment: It should be a comment instead of an answer!

Comment: var_dump() returns null

Comment: so your admission table has no records, pls insert some values and check it again